# Can't move FabricJS svg or group objects to the canvas top left corner

Tags: javascript, svg, fabricjs

I'm working on a FabricJS app where I want the user to move objects to the canvas origin by a simple click, even after rotating or scaling objects or a group of objects.
To do so, when clicking I perform the code below when the user click:

```
obj.left= obj.getBoundingRect().width/2;
obj.top=obj.getBoundingRect().height/2;
```

It works perfectly with rectangles or texts, but it doesn't work at all when using shape, svg or even group of objects. I have no idea why!

Below it's the complete code.

**IMPORTANT: Please enable cross-origin access in your browser for the svg to be loaded.**

```js
    this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('meCanvas', {
        preserveObjectStacking: true,
        height: 400,
        width: 400,
        backgroundColor: '#1F1F1F',
        canvasKey:'azpoazpoaz'
    });
   let rect = new fabric.Rect({
        fill: 'red',
        width: 200,
        height: 100,
        left: 100,
        top: 100,
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
        fontWeight: 'normal'
    });

    let text = new fabric.IText('Text', {
        fontFamily: 'Times',
        fontSize: 18,
        fill: 'white',
        left: 100,
        top: 100,
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
        fontWeight: 'normal'
    });

    let url = 'https://svgshare.com/i/9DX.svg';
    fabric.loadSVGFromURL(url,(objects,options)=> {

        let loadedObjects = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
        loadedObjects.left=50;
        loadedObjects.top=150;
        this.__canvas.add(loadedObjects);
    });

    let url2 = 'https://svgshare.com/i/9Cp.svg';
    fabric.loadSVGFromURL(url2,(objects,options)=> {

        let loadedObjects = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
        loadedObjects.left=100;
        loadedObjects.top=200;
        loadedObjects.angle=20;
        this.__canvas.add(loadedObjects);
    });

    this.__canvas.add(rect);
    this.__canvas.add(text);
    this.__canvas.renderAll();

    $('#pushorigin').click((e)=>{
        let obj = this.__canvas.getActiveObject();
        obj.left= obj.getBoundingRect().width/2;
        obj.top=obj.getBoundingRect().height/2;
        this.__canvas.requestRenderAll();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.3/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <div style='display: inline-block'>
        <div>
            <canvas id='meCanvas' ref='meFabric'/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button id='pushorigin'>Push to origin</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If you select the text or the rectangle and click the button "Push to origin", they will go to the origin (top left corner). But the same action doesn't work with the svg (triangle and the polygone) and it goes even worst if we stretch those svg or even rotating them, they won't go to the origin. Same thing when using a group of object!

I don't know what to do, I'm lost. I've googled for days and found nothing.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `originX: 'center',originY: 'center'` for all object then your solution will work.

```js
this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('meCanvas', {
  preserveObjectStacking: true,
  height: 400,
  width: 400,
  backgroundColor: '#1F1F1F',
  canvasKey: 'azpoazpoaz'
});
let rect = new fabric.Rect({
  fill: 'red',
  width: 200,
  height: 100,
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center',
  fontWeight: 'normal'
});

let text = new fabric.IText('Text', {
  fontFamily: 'Times',
  fontSize: 18,
  fill: 'white',
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center',
  fontWeight: 'normal'
});

let url = 'https://svgshare.com/i/9DX.svg';
fabric.loadSVGFromURL(url, (objects, options) => {

  let loadedObjects = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
  loadedObjects.set({
    left: 50,
    top: 150,
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center'
  })

  this.__canvas.add(loadedObjects);
});

let url2 = 'https://svgshare.com/i/9Cp.svg';
fabric.loadSVGFromURL(url2, (objects, options) => {
  let loadedObjects = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
  loadedObjects.set({
    left: 100,
    top: 200,
    angle: 20,
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center'
  })
  this.__canvas.add(loadedObjects);
});

this.__canvas.add(rect);
this.__canvas.add(text);
this.__canvas.renderAll();

$('#pushorigin').click((e) => {
  let obj = this.__canvas.getActiveObject();
  obj.set({
    left: obj.getBoundingRect().width / 2,
    top: obj.getBoundingRect().height / 2
  }).setCoords()
  this.__canvas.requestRenderAll();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.3/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<div style='display: inline-block'>
    <div>
        <canvas id='meCanvas' ref='meFabric'/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button id='pushorigin'>Push to origin</button>
    </div>
</div>
```